# Getting user's Google Account avatar without him signing in with Google

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-account

I have a web application where users can sign in with their username and password or with Google Account. If the email from their Google Account happens to be one of the users' email, this user is signed in. In the response from Google API on sign in I get their avatar.

Is it possible to get user's avatar from Google Account just by email without them having to sign in?

Comment: http://avatarapi.com

Answer (score 1):

While technically speaking a users profile info should be public.   You shouldn't need access to see a users google avatar.   The problem is that there is no way to search for a user based upon their `email address`.

I tried people api, gmail api, contacts api, google plus api.   None would allow me to search unauthenticated for a user based upon their email address.

## update

after google+ shutdown this workaround no longer works

The only thing I did find that worked was this.

```
http://www.google.com/profiles?q=myemail@gmail.com
```

Which will really only work if the user has a Google+ account.  You should be able to scrape the users id off of that then run an [Activities: search](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/search) which would return any posts they had made and in that contains.

```
"actor": {
    "id": "117200475532672775346",
    "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/117200475532672775346",
    "image": {
     "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAdVM/sHkU9F-AwwQ/photo.jpg?sz=50"
    },
```

Again all of this will only work if the user has a google+ account and actually uses it.

Comment: The link you provided no longer works, presumably because Google+ has been shut down.

Comment: Yes its shutdown now.   Making this workaround obslite.